# How to auto update a d3 grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following Mike Bostock's [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051), i am trying auto update the chart every 10 seconds.

I can achieve this by setting a timeout and deleting the whole svg before creating it again. Ex:

```
function updateBarChart(){

    d3.select("body").select("svg").remove();

    // Rest of the Code Similar to the Example
    //...

    setTimeout(updateBarChart, 10000);
}
```

However, this creates a blink effect when it deletes the old one and creates a new.

Is there a way i can do it better? Maybe with a nice animation?

[Full Code Here](https://bl.ocks.org/Raj-Kishan/e29dc5c79960ebd26fb00cc41124713a/206571f70b6d7107bb348a9cd0f5260b5df10fcc)

Any help is appreciated. :)

**UPDATE**

Removed the blink effect thanks to the examples provided by Gerardo Furtado. But i face a new problem now. If the length of the incoming Array increases, older bars with bigger width overlap and graph does not show up correctly.

Comment: *"Is there a way i can do it better?"*. Sure: what you have right now is not a **real** update, you're simply removing the element and repainting everything again. This is what I call a *lazy update*. It may be a valid and correct approach in very few circumstances. In 98.47% of the times, however, it just shows that the person that wrote the code is not familiar with D3.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You are right. I just started reading about d3 5-6 days ago. So, yes i am not very familiar. Can you please point me in a right direction? Like, where should i start or which methods i should look at if i want to avoid the Lazy Update route.

Comment: Well, for a proper answer you have to provide a [MCVE], preferably using blockbuilder. Meanwhile, read Mike Bostock's update series: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 Just like "The Godfather" it has part I, II and III (just click "next").

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Looked at the example you have given me and managed to remove the blink effect. But if the older bar's width is longer than the new bar(in case more data is added to the array), it does not show up correctly. Updated the question with blockbuilder url.

Comment: Please set up an example with two different data sets, so we can see the issue.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado : Updated https://bl.ocks.org/Raj-Kishan/e29dc5c79960ebd26fb00cc41124713a/206571f70b6d7107bb348a9cd0f5260b5df10fcc. As you can see, the when it loads new data after 5 seconds, the graph gets messy.